# @react-pdf/renderer 3.0.0 TypeError: ctx.embedImage is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-pdfrenderer

Here is a snippet of my code...

[image: Code Snippet]

I was trying to load the image from the public directory.

[image: Image Directory]

But it gives me this error.

[image: Error Result]

Comment: I am having the same problem. rebuild node-sass did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

then I use command: npm rebuild node-sass to update node version from 12 to 14. Now I am using node 14.20 to yarn start and the issue was gone